# Changing documentroot in Apache http.conf file stops PHP parsing

Tags: php, apache, module

- Windows 10 workstation
- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7.2.

I have installed Apache and PHP on a Windows 10 developer workstation and everything (including PHP) works beautifully. But when I change the `DocumentRoot` in the `http.conf` file, Apache stops sending .php files to the PHP engine.

Apache opens the .php files in the new directory, but the <?php> code no longer gets parsed and processed by the php engine (php.exe). Apache no longer runs those files through the php module.

Here is what I have changed in the http.conf file:

OLD SETTING:

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
```

NEW SETTING:

```
#DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
DocumentRoot "C:/WWW"

#<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
<Directory "C:/WWW">
```

When I change it back again, PHP works just fine.

I have also tried changing the `doc_root` setting in `php.ini`, but that does not help. Apache loads the .php page, but does not send it to the php server.

Comment: Put `LogLevel debug`, (or even some trace level), restart and try again.  Check your error_log for - hopefully - some useful messages.  Make sure the user running your Apache has proper permissions to `C:\WWW` as well.  When it does not work, what do you see in the browser?  A printout of the PHP code (i.e. not interpreted?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding.  The problem was a minor one.  In the fresh install of PHP 5.3, the `short_open_tag` in `PHP.ini` was defaulted to `Off`.   The phpinfo file in the Apache directory opened with `<?php>` and the file in the new directory opened with `<?>`, so it didn't parse.  I've changed the php.ini file with `short_open_tag = On` and all is well now.  In newer versions of PHP ... from 5.4 on up, the short open tag `<?>` will always work, regardless of the `short_open_tag` setting.

Simple little things can sometimes trip us up.